# Hibernate optional @ManyToOne with multiple @JoinColumn

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, join, orm

I have a this schema:

```
+---------+-----------+
| Cust_No | Cust_Name |
+---------+-----------+
|   12345 | ACME Inc. |
|   54321 | Foo Corp. |
+---------+-----------+

+---------+---------+--------+
| Addr_No | Cust_No | Street |
+---------+---------+--------+
|   10000 |   12345 | Broad. |
+---------+---------+--------+

+---------+---------+---------+-------------+
| Cntr_No | Cust_no | Addr_No | Description |
+---------+---------+---------+-------------+
|   98765 |   12345 |    NULL | PlatService |
|   56789 |   12345 |   10000 | GoldService |
|   45678 |   54321 |    NULL | SlvrService |
+---------+---------+---------+-------------+
```

and this entities:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Cust_No")
    private Long number;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "Cust_No", referencedColumnName = "Cust_No")
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(AddressKey.class)
public class Address {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Addr_No")
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Cust_No")
    private Long customerId;

    @Column(name = "Street")
    private String street;
}

@Entity
public class Contract {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Cntr_No")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Cust_No" referencedColumnName = "Cust_No", insertable = false, updateable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "Cust_No", referencedColumnName = "Cust_No",
        @JoinColumn(name = "Addr_No", referencedColumnName = "Addr_No"
    })
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Address address;

    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;
}
```

A `Contract` may be associated to a `Customer` or to a `Customer + Address`. First of all, it seems that Hibernate needs the `@NotFound` annotation otherwise it will throw exceptions like: `EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Address with id 54321` and that's weird since `@ManyToOne` should be `optional = true` by default.

Then, when I query for `Contract`s by `Customer.name`, Hibernate uses a `CROSS JOIN` that excludes all `Contract`s where `Addr_No` is `NULL`. Since `@ManyToOne` is optional by default, I would expect a `LEFT JOIN`, which would include `Contract`s with `null` `Address`es.

Using JPQL with an explicit `LEFT OUTER JOIN` works, but I don't have access to the build process of the query (that is built with Criteria API).

Question is: why an optional `@ManyToOne` uses a `CROSS JOIN`? Is it a bug?

Comment: I'm on WildFly 10, Hibernate 5.0.7 and SQL Server 2012.

Comment: so what is the relevance of the line "Using JPQL ... but I can't use JPQL, only the Criteria API" ? You can achieve the exact same thing (LEFT OUTER JOIN) with Criteria

Comment: I said that badly, I meant I can not explicitly modify the query (that is built with the Criteria API, but I can not mangle with it). I can add annotations to entities, though.